# How to make a python context manager

Tags: python, contextmanager

I define my class like this:

```
class Simple():
    def __init__(self):
        self.string = "Hello World"

    def __enter__(self):
        pass

    def __exit__(self):
        pass
```

and call it like this:

```
with Simple() as simple_test:
    print(simple_test.string)
```

I get the following error:

```
    print(simple_test.string)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string'
```

Why is my class `None`?

Comment: `simple_test` is assigned the return value of the `__enter__` method - you need to return `self` from the `__enter__` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `__enter__` method must return `self`:

```
def __enter__(self):
    return self
```

Comment: I think there's also an error in the __exit__() specification?

Comment: The `__exit__` method should only do the cleanup. It doesn't return anything...

Comment: My (finally realized) understanding is that it should be `__exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)`?

Comment: Yes, if you gonna use it inside your `__exit__`, you can. If you just want to `pass` it, and you added `__exit__` it just to implement context manager, you can leave the `__exit__` func without params (only self)

Comment: By the way, if it helped you, please accept the answer in order to help other people struggling with similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

`__enter__` should return whatever you want to bind in the `as` clause, see [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__enter__).

Because your `__enter__` doesn't return anything, the value bound to `simple_test` is `None`.

I think you want this:

```
class Simple():
    def __init__(self):
        self.string = "Hello World"

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self):
        pass
```